# Page scroll to top JQuery not working

Tags: jquery

I have installed Page scroll to top and it's not working. Nothing is showing.

Can someone help me out? My website is: http://www.vipjournal.net.

I just don't know what to do.

I have followed this steps. http://gazpo.com/2012/02/scrolltop/

Comment: Does your browser's JavaScript console reveal anything?

Comment: Nope. Tested in chrome and IE. I also have menu that running on jquery and it's working.

Comment: I'm sorry, but there is an outrageous amount of code running on that page at once, and it's impossible to narrow down where your problem might be. You'll have to devise a small, reproduceable test case for us.

Comment: If I put that code in simple Html page it will probably work, but my problem is in my website exactly. That is why I need help, half of it is just topics. I will try to delete it from source code, and present to you.

Comment: When I execute `$(document).scrollTop(0);` in Firebug on your website I get to the top of the page...

Comment: Ok, I have removed most of the unnecesary source code. It is clean now.

Comment: Robert, so if the function working why the link is not showing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is in this :

```
.scrollup {
    background: url("html/icon_top.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    bottom: 50px;
    display: none;
    height: 40px;
    opacity: 0.3;
    position: fixed;
    right: 100px;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    width: 40px;
}
```

The url which you have given in the background- "html/icon_top.png" seems invalid. So the Scroll to Up arrow is there in your footer (right side). But its not showing cause the url can't find the image. So I suggest you to check for the proper url.

At present you can see your script working by clicking at the right side of footer. ( 1 inch far form the right side and in the vertical middle of footer.)

Comment: Wolllaaa. That was the problem, I wrote full path and it worked. Thank you guys for help. As my site is huge this really helps me.

Comment: If you found this helpful, you can mark this as answer. So the question can be closed. Thank you! :)

Comment: I don't get it, why is it not working in IE? but in chrome works great.